# ADODB recordset.open is duplication records

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Excel VBA recordset.open command is returning double the number of records

This code was working for years and now we upgraded to windows 10 and excel 2016 and it is doing this.

Comment: Show full code (variables definition, opening recordset, retrieving records count).

Comment: Sorry, I found the issue.  Someone had duplicated records in a joined table

Comment: @user1093735,, since problem has been fixed & the reason was basic mistake therefore please delete the question,, Or you can use UNIQUE record set method also instead of deleting DUPLICATE records !!

Answer (score 0):

*Since by mistake duplicate records has been entered (`as you have written in Comments above`) therefore, instead of deleting records you may read UNIQUE records.*

Below are few possible VBA code lines help to get Unique records.

```
rs.Open "SELECT Distinct ColumnName AS C FROM TableName
```

Or

```
strSQL = "SELECT Distinct(COLNAME) from [SheetName$] "
```